# Spark applications stuck at ACCEPTED state

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I installed a fresh instance of Cloudera 5.4 on a single Ubuntu 14.04 server and want to run one of spark applications.

This is the command:

```
sudo -uhdfs spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/spark-examples-1.3.0-cdh5.4.5-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.5.jar
```

This is the output:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/avro-tools-1.7.6-cdh5.4.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/08/29 12:07:56 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at chd2.moneyball.guru/104.131.78.0:8032
15/08/29 12:07:56 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
15/08/29 12:07:56 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (1750 MB per container)
15/08/29 12:07:56 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
15/08/29 12:07:56 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
15/08/29 12:07:56 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
15/08/29 12:07:57 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.5-1.cdh5.4.5.p0.7/jars/spark-examples-1.3.0-cdh5.4.5-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.5.jar -> hdfs://chd2.moneyball.guru:8020/user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1440861466017_0007/spark-examples-1.3.0-cdh5.4.5-hadoop2.6.0-cdh5.4.5.jar
15/08/29 12:07:57 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
15/08/29 12:07:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: hdfs
15/08/29 12:07:57 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: hdfs
15/08/29 12:07:57 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(hdfs); users with modify permissions: Set(hdfs)
15/08/29 12:07:57 INFO Client: Submitting application 7 to ResourceManager
15/08/29 12:07:57 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1440861466017_0007
15/08/29 12:07:58 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:07:58 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.hdfs
     start time: 1440864477580
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://chd2.moneyball.guru:8088/proxy/application_1440861466017_0007/
     user: hdfs
15/08/29 12:07:59 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:08:00 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:08:01 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:08:02 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:08:03 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:08:04 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:08:05 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:08:06 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED)
15/08/29 12:08:07 INFO Client: Application report for application_1440861466017_0007 (state: ACCEPTED
.....
```

It will show the last line in a loop. 
Can you help please? Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 4):

I increased `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`. Everything is ok now

Answer (score 3):

This can happen when Yarn's slots are occupied by other jobs and the cluster is at its capacity. The job gets stuck in the ACCEPTED state waiting for its turn to run. Can you check from Yarn Resource Manager UI to see if anything else is running on the cluster which might be slowing this app down? The RM UI can be accessed by going to http://104.131.78.0:8088, assuming that your RM Address is still 104.131.78.0 as shown in your logs. You should be able to see 1) if any other application is running on your cluster, and 2) navigate to the Spark UI running on http://ApplicationMasterAddress:4040 for further analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue on Spark 1.5.2, and was able to fix this by using a Scala `object` to contain my `main` function, instead of a Scala `class`